# mapping Json object with for each attributing class and data to each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to write jason data into separate divs with class .name and data-key za data attr. I have problem with data and getting the right index for that.

Here is my buggy attempt. Console.log writes all keys, but the last function doesn't give divs the data attr

```
$.post( "http://0.0.0.0:9292/api/links", function( data ) {
        var names = data.map(function (i) {
        return i['link'].name
        });
        var keys = data.map(function (i) {
        return i['link']['key']
        });
        var container = document.querySelector(".link-names");
           names.forEach(function(name) {
              var div = document.createElement('div');
              div.innerHTML = name;
              $(div).addClass("name");
              container.appendChild(div);
           });


        $.each((".name"), function(index) {
          $(this).data("key", keys[index]);
          console.log(keys[index]);
        });
```

Comment: You won't be able to *see* the data attribute added, as jQuery stores them internally.

Comment: ! o! so how can I see the key for each (".name") el using console

Comment: Just repeat your loop after you set. For example, after you set the keys just do `$('.name').each(function(){ console.log($(this).data('key')); });`

Comment: `$.each((".name"), function(index) {
    console.log($(this).data());
});` will log the entire data associated with the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try with this updated code

```
$.post( "http://0.0.0.0:9292/api/links", function( data ) {
    var names = data.map(function (i) {
    return i['link'].name
    });
    var keys = data.map(function (i) {
    return i['link']['key']
    });
    var container = document.querySelector(".link-names");
       names.forEach(function(name) {
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.innerHTML = name;
          $(div).addClass("name");
          container.appendChild(div);
       });


    $(".name").each(function(index) {
      $(this).data("key", keys[index]);
      console.log(keys[index]);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `$` in `('.names')` `$.each` try this,

```
$.each($(".name"), function(index) {
// ----^ use $ here
    $(this).data("key", keys[index]);
    console.log(keys[index]);
});
```

or simply,

```
$(".name").each(function(index) {
    $(this).data("key", keys[index]);
    console.log(keys[index]);
});
```

You can add `key` while `adding element` in `container` like,

```
var i=0;
var container = document.querySelector(".link-names");
names.forEach(function(name) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = name;
      $(div).addClass("name");
      $(div).data("key", keys[i]);// set data here
      container.appendChild(div);  
      i++;            
});
```

Comment: good catch, but that wouldn't have actually prevented the loop from running as `$.each(selector, function)` is valid